# Funnel-like device for putting non-liquids into a whipped cream dispenser?

Tags: equipment, whipped-cream

I use an iSi whipped cream dispenser to make things besides whipped cream, such as microwaved chocolate cake, or coffee foam to top desserts.  Pouring cream or sugar into the small opening at the top is easy.  Pouring things like cake batter or coffee in gel form is not as easy.  I tried using a funnel, but it just got clogged and made a mess.  The best technique I've found so far is to fold some parchment paper in half to create a channel, and have a helper hold it while I pour the mixture onto it.

Does anyone have a better technique for this?

Comment: For coffee in gel form, have you considered making the gel in the dispenser (i.e. pouring in the liquid before it sets)?

Comment: I haven't made many of these gels, but for the coffee, the recipe calls for allowing it to set, and then applying an immersion blender to it until it is "barely pourable".  In that case, I cannot let it set in the dispenser.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that the problem with using a funnel isn't just the size of your specific funnel(s)?

There are plenty of wide-mouthed funnels out there that you should probably try, if you haven't already, such as this Cuisinox:

[image: Cuisinox Funnel]

Or this Norpro:

[image: Norpro Funnel]

Either of those look like they'd fit into my own iSi pretty easily, but if you're sure that none of them will work for you, then I think the next best thing would be a piping bag with no tip or coupler. If you don't have one then you can always use the "snip a corner off a ziploc bag" workaround.

Comment: I think the main problem I had was finding funnels with the measurements that were both (a) suitable and (b) given in the product description.  I'll order one of these soon.  Thanks!